# What is a good way of plotting a histogram of a multi valued variable in python?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, anaconda, seaborn

I have some data in a pandas.Series, with a length of 10,000,000.
Plotting the histogram directly makes combines similar values together, 
making them indistinguishable. 
What is a proper way of visualizing the values?

Answer (score 1):

Matplotlib, pandas and seaborn all provide a histogram function. Each of these functions always have an optional argument specifying the number of bins, i.e. the resolution of the histogram. Change this value untill you get to the resolution you like.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = np.random.randn(1000)
series = pd.Series(data)
#Change the number of bins to affect the histogram resolution
data.hist(bins = 100)
```